# IOS Change Camera icon for custom camera overlay

Tags: ios, flash, camera, camera-overlay

How and where do I find the "Change Camera" and "Camera Flash on/off" icon used in the native camera application on the iPhone. I would like to use this in my camera overlay but I cannot find this icons anywhere. Can someone please tell me where I might find these icon or do I have to create them programmatically?

Comment: Could you please give me the complete path? How do I access it on my phone?

Comment: that's the complete path for the app bundle, you can find the images in there. You can use `scp` to get the files.

Comment: Is there a documentation/link I can read to get the whole information as I still don't have enough information to find it. So far, I have looked at Organizer to see if it gives me access to the apps but it does not give access to any native iPhone app. I also googled scp but it's not leading to an answer. I would appreciate if there is a documentation I can read to learn about how to this.

Comment: not reaally, sorry, as this is not official.

Comment: Okay. I can't jailbreak my phone because after searching a bit, this is what it kinda points to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the [UIKit Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor). Not sure if those images are in the iOS Simulator, but it's worth a try.